# Which rights are needed to add widgets to the desktop?

Tags: xprivacy

I installed xprivacy on my rooted device and blocked all privileges to the "Google Search"-app. Now i cannot add any widgets any more.

Which rights do I have to allow and how could I find out such questions my self?

Answer (score 0):

That's usually the [`INSTALL_SHORTCUT`](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=perms#INSTALL_SHORTCUT) (resp. [`UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT`](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=perms#UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT)) permission – which might be present multiple times, as it's declared by the resp. launcher. To find out yourself, just follow the links I've given :)

**EDIT:** As stated in [their FAQ](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#FAQ25), Xprivacy is no "permission manager", but a "privacy manager", and thus only cares for privacy-related permissions. Installing shortcuts is one of those permissions it does *not* care for (explicitly stated), so this is rather an unintended side-effect to be dealt with an update (fix) from the Xprivacy dev(s).

Comment: I cannot find no such permission in xPrivacy. related: https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy/issues/672

Comment: I don't know how Xprivacy names them (and in which "tree" they are), but those are the names of the *permissions* responsible for this (see #3 in the issue you've linked). The first comment even suggests it's not covered at all (uh? It's not a "permissions manager", but just a "privacy manager"?) – which somehow contradicts with what you report (this "uncovered" permission being revoked). As stated over there, this must be an unintended side-effect then – nothing we can help with here (but thanks for the link, though!)